# Hi, how to get the YTD disregarding the date range parameter set in my ssrs report

Tags: date, reporting-services

To make my question easier to understand, I have attached here a screenshot showing my ytd...it should have been only 63M but since the January t0 March last year was added to current year, the total became 77M.I want to know the expression to use so that I can only retrieve my current ytd.  I hope it is clearer by now. Apologies for the confusion.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwK0X.png)

1. Report showing the last year 2021 and current with the previous month comparative
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7xyd.png)
2. The chart showing the data per month added ex. January 2022+ January 2021.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWCXT.png)

Comment: I'm not clear on what your problem is. Is it that your chart is currently showing too many months? Could you **edit your question** and, based on the sample data in your first image, show exactly what you expect to see in the chart.

Comment: Really thanks for the immediate reply. My problem actually is in my report, I want the end user to select the start and end date dynamically but would work both in the matrix and my charts. The repot works fine as it retrieves the data per month both current year and past year. However in my chart, it added both the current and previous month data, say the January in my chart shows the total of Jan 2021 and January 2022 when it should only retrieve the January 2022. I need to know therefore the expression to be used in my chart where the current date would base in the year as selected.

Comment: so if in the parameter the start date is January 2021 and end date is March 31, 2022, my chart would show only the ytd monthly January to March 2022 with the comparative previous months January 2021 to march 2021:) I need to show my last year because my report is designed as inorder to pull the comparative result, I have to select the start date parameter from last year...thanks so much for the help Sir.

Comment: Can you EDIT your question rather than using the comments and show exactly what you expect to see, if much easier to understand if I can visualise it.